# How to factor out yaml code repetitions with small differences?

Tags: yaml, circleci

The following yaml repeats the same block with only minor differences.

```
 jobs:
    "python2":
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: make check
            command: >
               virtualenv -p $(which python2.7) venv
               && make check

    "python3":
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run:
            name: make check
            command: >
               virtualenv -p $(which python3.6) venv
               && make check
```

Between the two blocks only a substring (the python binary name python2.7 vs python3.6) is different in a nested value.

What is the best way to avoid repetition in this code?

---

While [anchors and extend](http://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html) look promising, I was [not able to use](http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=ICAKc3RlcHM6ICZjb21tb25TdGVwcwogIC0gY2hlY2tvdXQKICAtIHJ1bjoKICAgIG5hbWU6IG1ha2UgY2hlY2sKICAgIGNvbW1hbmQ6ICIiCgoKam9iczoKICAicHl0aG9uMiI6CiAgICAgPDw6ICpjb21tb25TdGVwcwogICAgIAoK) the following yaml block with an extend attempt.

```
steps: &commonSteps
  - checkout
  - run:
    name: make check
    command: ""


version: 2
jobs:
  "python2":
     <<: *commonSteps
```

---

If anyone is interested, this is for a [circle-ci config file](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/sample-config/)

Comment: I know no way to mark some YAML-subtree as a copy of other with some replacements. Anchors are actually for precise copy of subtree.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think I need something like a function call on a yaml file. I know [jsonnet](http://jsonnet.org/) can be used for templating json. Maybe templating is the way to go here.

Comment: Yes, "templating" could help, but this would be not a pure YAML anymore. That is, you may choose any template engine which you like, and try to use it. But you cannot ask about "which template is the best" on Stack Overflow. However, you may ask about things **specifically** related with circle-ci - it could be that given configuration mechanism has some type of macros or so. Because of that, adding "circleci" tag could be very helpful for your question.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the difference.

Instead of setting a Python version in a step, use the appropriate Docker image for that version of Python in the CircleCI config. Then, the steps will be identical and a YAML anchor/alias can be used.